# JavaScript: Adding Variables

Tags: javascript

I am making a reservation system. I want to program this so that if the user clicks on button with class A, their total price gets increased by 7.50. Same for button with class B, class C etc.

I tried coding it like this:

```
var price = 0;
        if (button.className === "A")
        {
            price + 7.50;
        }

        if (button.className === "B")
        {
            price + 11;
        }

        if (button.className === "C")
        {
            price + 13;
        }
```

But the only output I get is 0!

I'm probably making a rookie mistake, but can anyone help me out?

Comment: Also learn about `else if`

Comment: `var price = {A:7.5, B:11, C:13}[button.className] || 0;` :-)

Answer (score 3):

You want `+=`

```
price += 13;
```

This is equiv to:

```
price = price + 13;
```

Calling `price + 13` will do nothing, since your never re-assigning the result back to `price`.

Comment: Strangely enough, it doesn't work. It gives me the correct value for each button but it doesn't add them together.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I think your answer is almost the solution, but it just doesn't work completely as I want it to..

Comment: Without seeing the larger context of this code it's hard to say, but it looks like you might be reassigning the value to zero with `var price = 0;` each time the button is clicked. Which would mean that it is successfully adding the value - to zero.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things I'm hoping you would learn here:

You can write an `alert(button.className);` at the top of your code to tell you the class name of the button.

Then, as one of the guys pointed out, use `else if`. For example, if it passes the first condition, it won't have to go through the other two. Here's an example:

```
var dayToday = 'Monday';
if (dayToday === 'Monday') {
    doThis();
}
else if (dayToday === 'Tuesday') {
    doThat();
}

// Since today is Monday, it will pass the first "if condition"
// It won't have to check the 2nd condition
```

And the `price + 7.50` just calculates and returns the resulting value, but it doesn't store that value anywhere. What you want to do is store it back to `price` by using `price = price + 7.50` (or `price += 7.50`)